# How to use utility classes (like Rectangle) in VBA?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access

I am using vba a lot with ms-access. Now I needed the functionality as provided by the Rectangle-class in C#. As there is a way to use several windows classes in vba (Like MSXML2.DOMDocument60) I wonder if there is a way to use the C# System.drawing.Rectangle class in vba directly?

Clarification:

- I dont want to write C# code
- I dont want to use wrapper-classes

Comment: You will need to use a technique called COM Interop.  There are plenty of examples on SO and on the web.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford : I did not find an example. Can you show me one? I want to use the Rectangle class.

Comment: I did this search in google `vba c# com interop`.  It gives many links, including to this site, that you can start reading up on.

Comment: @ Brian M Stafford: I think you misunderstood my question. The search tells me how to write C# code which can be called in vba. I already know how to do this. I dont want to write C# code. I want to use the native C#-classes from vba. I dont want to write a new Rectangle-class. I want to use the System.Drawing.Rectangle class from the .NET Framework directly.

Comment: Exactly.  So you will need to create a COM Interop DLL in a language of your choice that wraps the Rectangle class.  In essence you are creating an interface between .NET and COM.  You cannot get to it directly.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford: ok. Thanks. This is what I wanted to know. Writing wrapper-classes and having to deploy the dll to all clients is probably a lot more work than just writing my own RectangleClass in vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian M Stafford writes in the comments there seems to be no way to access the .net-Framework-classes from vba directly.